# Convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2^{-n}}{n^2}z^n$ when $\mid z\mid =2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that it converges everywhere on the circle $\mid z\mid=2$, but how do I show it? Something like comparison test or alternating series test doesn't work. Is there any general theorem to see the convergence on the boundary? Or is it something that is hard to see?

Comment: It is absolutely convergent...

Comment: $$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{ - n} }}{{n^2 }}z^n } } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{ - n} }}{{n^2 }}\left| z \right|^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{ - n} }}{{n^2 }}2^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6} <  + \infty 
$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I missed that point.. I was actually looking for more general case, for example where it converges on the half the circle, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy Hadamard, $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{2^{-n}}{n^2}}}=\dfrac1{\dfrac12}=2$.

When $z=2$, we get $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}6$.

When $|z|=2$, the sum is absolutely convergent, by comparison with $\zeta(2)$.